# I can't submit a form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to submit a form with JavaScript but I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'form.submit()')

This is the relevant code:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form"),
    submit = document.getElementById("submit");
submit.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    form.submit();
}, false);
```

Edit: this is the relevant html code:

```
<form method="post" action="www.example.com" id="form">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide the HTML that you are attaching this to.

Comment: I've now edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you named your `submit` button as `submit`. So, when you say

```
form.submit();
```

It tries to execute the button object, which is not a function. So, the fix would be to change the id of the `submit` button.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Yz3/)

Comment: I'm doing that in the first line of code.

Comment: @user2872841 Well, I believe it may be because you're using an reserved word, change the `id` to something more unique like, `fillform`

Comment: Thanks MackieeE and thefourtheye! I had tried changing the name of the variable to something more unique like mySubmit and it didn't help, but I didn't think the id would interfere with the javascript code. It now works after changing the id.